# How to quickly zero out an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

I am currently doing it in a for loop, and I know in C there is the ZeroMemory API, however that doesn't seem to be available in C#. Nor does the somewhat equivalent Array.fill from Java exist either. I am just wondering if there is an easier/faster way?

Comment: You don't need to clear it during initialization.  Your post doesn't indicate whether this is during initialization or after you've put data into the array.

Comment: After i've put data into the array.

Comment: Dustin: I think it is rather rude to just tell me a google search would have worked. Obviously, my mind is different than yours, and a look through "zero out memory in c#" did not yield me Array.Clear()

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Try [Array.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx):

> Sets a range of elements in the  Array
>   to zero, to `false`, or to
>   `null`
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic), depending
>   on the element type.

Comment: The description seems to be outdated, and does not cover all types. It's sets the elements to its `default` value depending on the element type. Example for `char` the default value would be: `'\0'`

Answer (score 61):

- C++: `memset(array, 0, array_length_in_bytes);`
- C++11: `array.fill(0);`
- C#: `Array.Clear(array, startingIndex, length);`
- Java: `Arrays.fill(array, value);`

Comment: I'd against the c-function `memset` in C++ in favor of the C++ `std::fill`. The `memset` usually in optimized code becomes a call to the library `memset`, whilst `std::fill` becomes just a few assembly instructions, without a call at all.

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE**

Based on the [benchmark](https://manski.net/2012/12/net-array-clear-vs-arrayx-0-performance/) regarding `Array.Clear()` and `array[x] = default(T)` performance, we can state that there are **two major cases** to be considered when zeroing an array:

A) There is an array that is **1..76 items long**;

B) There is an array that is **77 or more items long**.

So the **orange** line on the plot represents `Array.Clear()` approach.

The **blue** line on the plot represents `array[x] = default(T)` approach (iteration over the array and setting its values to `default(T)`).

[image]

You can write once a Helper to do this job, like this:

```
public static class ArrayHelper
{
    // Performance-oriented algorithm selection
    public static void SelfSetToDefaults<T>(this T[] sourceArray)
    {
        if (sourceArray.Length <= 76)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.Length; i++)
            {
                sourceArray[i] = default(T);
            }
        }
        else { // 77+
             Array.Clear(
                 array: sourceArray,
                 index: 0,
                 length: sourceArray.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
someArray.SelfSetToDefaults();
```

**Remarks:**

This test was undertaken having in mind .NET Framework 4.x

**Edit (.NET6):**

In .NET6 the `Array.Clear()` command is now faster for N > ~25 according to [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)'s comment.

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.x, `Array.Clear()` is faster for `N > ~75`, but in .NET 6 I see that `Array.Clear()` is now faster for `N > ~25`.

Answer (score 19):

```
Array.Clear(integerArray, 0, integerArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 15):

Several people have posted answers, then deleted them, saying that in any language a for loop will be equally performant as a memset or FillMemory or whatever.

For example, a compiler might chunk it into 64-bit aligned pieces to take advantage of a 64bit zero assignment instruction, if available.  It will take alignment and stuff into consideration.  Memset's implementation is certainly not trivial.

one [memset.asm](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:CxjWA5P3cY0J:intelliwiki.kylesblog.com/index.php/Memset.asm+memset+asm&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).  Also see [memset-is-faster-than-simple-loop.html](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t486007-memset-is-faster-than-simple-loop.html).

Never underestimate the infinite deviousness of compiler and standard library writers.

Comment: I did a test with my for loop vs Array.Clear(). Array.Clear() 2 million times in a loop for a 4K array took 620 ms. The for loop took 13030 ms.

Comment: @esac And while that definitely answers your question, it's still an open question as to whether that remains true for all operating systems and hardware.  I agree that Array.Clear() is going to be at least as fast as a for loop and probably faster, which makes Array.Clear() the obvious choice.  (Plus, it's easier to read.)

Comment: @Richard `Array.Clear()` is slower than `for` for very small arrays (`1 <= N < ~25-75`) though, owing to `Array.Clear`'s internal logic for parameter validation and getting the dimensions/bounds of the array.

Answer (score 5):

Calling the method by using dll import.Its fast and easy to use :)

```
 [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
 public static extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int byteCount);
```

c is the value you want to set in the memory

OR

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="RtlZeroMemory")]
public unsafe static extern bool ZeroMemory(byte* destination, int length);
```

this only sets the given array to zero

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for I wrote this in visual basic however I'm sure you can convert it.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    'import Kernel32 so we can use the ZeroMemory Windows API function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
    Public Sub ZeroMemory(ByVal addr As IntPtr, ByVal size As IntPtr)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ZeroArray(array As ArrayList)
        'Iterate from 0 to the lenght of the array zeroing each item at that index
        For i As Integer = 0 To array.Count - 1
            'Pin the array item in memory
            Dim gch As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc((array(i)), GCHandleType.Pinned)
            'Get the memory address of the object pinned
            Dim arrayAddress As IntPtr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject()
            'Get size of the array
            Dim arraySize As IntPtr = CType(array.Count, IntPtr)
            'Zero memory at the current index address in memory
            ZeroMemory(arrayAddress, arraySize)
            gch.Free()
        Next

    End Sub


    Sub Main()
        'Initialize ArrayList with items
        Dim strArray As New ArrayList From {
            "example one",
            "example two",
            "example three"
        }

        'Pass array as parameter to a function which will iterate through the arraylist zeroing each item in memory
        ZeroArray(strArray)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```