# How to clear an array in Visual C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of ints.  They start out with 0, then they get filled with some values.  Then I want to set all the values back to 0 so that I can use it again, or else just delete the whole array so that I can redeclare it and start with an array of all 0s.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407715/how-to-quickly-zero-out-an-array

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can call [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx):

```
int[] x = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    x[i] = 5;
}
Array.Clear(x, 0, x.Length);
```

Alternatively, depending on the situation, you may find it clearer to just create a new array instead. In particular, you then don't need to worry about whether some other code still has a reference to the array and expects the old values to be there.

I can't recall ever calling `Array.Clear` in my own code - it's just not something I've needed.

(Of course, if you're about to replace all the values anyway, you can do that without clearing the array first.)

Comment: Any array also implements the ***non-generic*** `IList` interface which has a `Clear` method. Saying `((IList)x).Clear();` also "clears" the array instance, although this is not well [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340970.aspx). If the array is actually one-dimensional and zero-indexed, it also "magically" implements the generic `IList<>` interface which has *another* method also called `Clear`. If you say `((IList<int>)x).Clear();` you get a run-time exception! It is a subtlety that these two explicit interface implementations in `Array` behave differently.

Comment: Thank you for the comment about some code having reference to the array! Doing s1 = s2; and Array.Clear(s2, 0, s2.Length), it took me time before realizing what I've done. Thanks!