# Clearing an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I have a structure which has an array of numbers in it. I want to erase all contents of the array and then free the allocated memory. How would I do that?

Comment: can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673512/how-to-clear-an-array) solve your question?

Comment: better to post your code than only describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to free some allocated memory, there is no need to "clear" it. Take the following `struct`, for example:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int * my_numbers;
    // other fields
} my_struct_t;
```

The way to free the memory as you described it would be as follows:

```
my_struct_t bar;
bar.my_numbers = malloc(...);

// do some stuff with your struct

free(bar.my_numbers);
```

But since you mention it in your question, the best way to "zero out" or "clear" a dynamically allocated array would probably be the standard [`memset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) function from `<string.h>`:

```
memset(bar.my_numbers, 0, N * sizeof(int));
```

Where `N` is the amount of members in your array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show us the definition of the struct type and how you allocate it, but I'll try to cover all the bases:

First of all, in C "erasing" array contents usually means overwriting the elements with an out-of-band value (e.g., for an `int` array that's only supposed to contain non-negative elements, you'd overwrite the elements with a `0`, or for an array of pointers you'd overwrite all the elements with `NULL`).

If you want to set all the *bytes* in the array elements to `0`, you can use the `memset` library function like so:

```
memset( arr, 0, sizeof arr );
```

Otherwise, you will need to write a loop:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < num_elements( arr ); i++ )
  arr[i] = some_default_value;
```

where `num_elements( arr )` is simply the number of elements in that array, which you somehow have to keep track of.

If you defined the array as a *fixed-size* array in the structure definition, such as

```
struct foo {
  ...
  int arr[10];
  ...
};
```

then you can't resize the array, nor can you free the memory for the array separately from the entire struct instance.  IOW, if you allocate the instance as

```
struct foo obj;
```

then you can't free the memory manually.  If you allocate it as

```
struct foo *obj = malloc( sizeof *obj );
```

then you can't free `obj->arr` independently of `obj`.

If the struct member is simply a pointer that you assign the result of `malloc` or `calloc` to, such as

```
struct foo {
  ...
  int *arr;
  ...
};

struct foo obj;
obj.arr = malloc( sizeof *obj.arr * 10 );
```

then you *can* resize the array:

```
int *tmp = realloc( obj.arr, sizeof *obj.arr * 20 );
if ( tmp )
  obj.arr = tmp;
```

and free it separately of the struct instance:

```
free( obj.arr );
```

If you allocate the struct instance dynamically, then it only gets a little more complicated:

```
struct foo *obj = malloc( sizeof *obj );
if ( !obj )
   // memory error, bail out here

obj->arr = malloc( sizeof *obj->arr * 10 );
if ( !obj->arr )
{
  free( obj ); // release partially-allocated memory first
  // bail out here
}

// do stuff with obj

free( obj->arr );  // release arr first
free( obj );       // release obj
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put like :
struct.arrayname[i] = 0;
in a for loop.
and as far as i know data types in an structure does not take up memory as long as they are used. hope this helps.