# Fastest way in c# to clear portions of an array or move portions around

Tags: c#, arrays

what is the fastest way in c# to manipulate array of short ints? I miss things like memset or mempcy and memmove.

I need to clear (set to 0) portions of an array and move portions around (like shifting values to different indices)

To be more precise: I have a huge array that I have to modify. Sometime I have to clear portions of that array, setting them to 0. Other times I have to shift data around inside the same array. I therefore need to operate on the same Array already allocated

Comment: What research have you undertaken? Bench tests? etc

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find really an alternative to just a for loop

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Have you tried `Buffer.BlockCopy` or `Array.Copy`?

Comment: oh wow thanks for the tip! I did not know it! I have to operate on the same array, I am not sure it is a good idea to create a new array everytime.

Comment: Thank you everybody, you have been great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array in `c#` will already be allocated with the default value of the type, so `memset` to `0` is usually irrelevant. You will never get a "*dirty*" array on construction.

For copy operations, you can use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for typed copying or [`Buffer.Blockcopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for raw byte copying.

Both of these support copying from/to the same array, <s>you just have to be careful not to provide overlapping idices.</s>

Edit:

For clearing out data you can use [`Array.Clear`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407715/how-to-quickly-zero-out-an-array)

Comment: Thanks, I may have explained better my situation though. I always write poor questions :(. I have a huge array that I have to modify. Sometime I have to clear portion of that array, setting to 0. Other times I have to shift data around inside the same array. I therefore need to operate on the same Array already allocated.

Comment: @sebas What's stopping you from operating on the Array in place?

Comment: I did not benchmark it, but I have the hinch that a simple for loop on an array in  c# is slower than a old school memset/memcpy operation

Comment: Correction: The `Array.Copy` and `Buffer.BlockCopy` handles overlapping sorce and destination areas.

Comment: @sebas (1) Why do you need a for loop? (2) Even without a for loop, it will most likely be slower than low level C++ code. You can always just drop to unsafe code and p/invoke memset/memcpy directly.

Comment: I presume something like Buffer.BlockCopy uses already lowlevel memory access functions. I just wonder why a BlockCopy exists and a BlockSet doesn't

Comment: @sebas See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407715/how-to-quickly-zero-out-an-array

Answer (score 0):

For clearing a part of an array you can just use a method like:

```
public static void Clear(short[] arr, int start, int len) {
  int end = start + len;
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) arr[i] = 0;
}
```

For copying, you can use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods. They also handle copying within the same array, even if the source and destination areas overlap.

Comment: thanks, I just fear that the performance of a for is not what I could get if I could access to the memory with low level functions

Comment: @sebas: That depends on whether you need good performance or absolute maximum performance. A regular loop over an array is optimised by the compiler so that it only does a range check once, not for every array access, so it performs fairly well. You can shave off a few percent on the execution time by using pointers to access the data directly, but not very much.

Comment: yep, your observations are correct. Unluckily the performance is critical (talking about a 3D game) and the array could be huge...so I was looking for the best solutions.