# C# equivalent code for ZeroMemory

Tags: c#, c++, memory, zero

I am using the following code to make partitions in usb drive.

```
char str[128];
    wsprintf(str,"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", i);
hDevice = CreateFile( ,"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL );

LARGE_INTEGER dimDiscoD;
LARGE_INTEGER dimDiscoE;
LARGE_INTEGER dimDiscoF;
LARGE_INTEGER dimDiscoG;
DISK_GEOMETRY_EX pDiskGeometryEx;

DWORD dwBytesReturned;
BOOL r = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX, NULL, 0, &pDiskGeometryEx, sizeof(pDiskGeometryEx), &dwBytesReturned, NULL );

dimDiscoG.QuadPart = DIM_DISCOG;
dimDiscoD.QuadPart = (( pDiskGeometryEx.DiskSize.QuadPart - dimDiscoG.QuadPart )/6) * 4;
dimDiscoE.QuadPart = dimDiscoD.QuadPart/4;
dimDiscoF.QuadPart = dimDiscoE.QuadPart;

CREATE_DISK pCreateDisk;
ZeroMemory(&pCreateDisk,sizeof(CREATE_DISK));

DWORD dwBytesReturned;
pCreateDisk.PartitionStyle =  PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
pCreateDisk.Mbr.Signature = 0xA4B57310;

DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK, (LPVOID)&pCreateDisk, sizeof(pCreateDisk), NULL, 0, &dwBytesReturned, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL)

DWORD junk1;

DeviceIoControl(hDevice,IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &junk1, NULL);

int SectorSize=pDiskGeometryEx.Geometry.BytesPerSector;

DWORD szNewLayout = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)+4*sizeof (PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);
DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX *dl = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX*) new BYTE[szNewLayout];
ZeroMemory(dl,szNewLayout);
```

...................

```
dl->PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
dl->PartitionCount = 4;// specify AT LEAST 4 partitions!!!
dl->Mbr.Signature = 0xA4B57310; //

DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, dl, szNewLayout, NULL, 0, &junk, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL) )

DWORD junk;
DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &junk, NULL);

CloseHandle(hDevice);
delete dl;
```

I am converting the above code into C#.   how can I convert the following line into c#?
ZeroMemory(&pCreateDisk,sizeof(CREATE_DISK));

Comment: Can you please help to convert the following line into c#? DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX dl = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) new BYTE[szNewLayout];

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407715/how-to-quickly-zero-out-an-array

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `ZeroMemory` in C#; all byte arrays you allocate are zeroed out implicitly because zero is the default value for all integral types (and also of `Guid`, which seems to be indirectly involved here).